# Def is repeating when variables are called outside function

Tags: python

I am trying to allow a user to first select if they want to define their name, then outputting either their chosen name or a randomly selected name.
I can play with the positioning of the inputs to either get the function to work fine with n or y but not both.

I want to call the username later on, and when I do so it loops back to ask the user input again.

```
import random

rando_username = ['Yoda', 'Han', 'Luke', 'General Kenobi', 'Mace Windu', 'Padme', 'Anakin', 'Jar Jar Binks']
random_username = random.choice(rando_username)

user_name_choice = input('Would you like to choose your own name for the duel? y/n')

user_choice = input('What shall we call you?')

def username():
    if user_name_choice == 'y':
        username = user_choice
    else:
        username = random_username
    return username

rando_opponent = ['Darth Vader', 'Darth Sidious', 'Darth Maul', 'Kylo Ren', 'Jabba the Hutt', 'Moff Gideon', 'Jango Fett', 'General Grievous']
random_opponent = random.choice(rando_opponent)

opponent_name_choice = input('Hello there, {}! Would you like to name your enemy? y/n'.format(username()))

opponent_choice = input('What shall we call your enemy?')

def opponent_name():
    if opponent_name_choice == 'y':
        opponent_name = opponent_choice  
    else:
         opponent_name = random_opponent
    return opponent_name

print ('Excellent choice {}, your opponent is {}!'.format(username(), opponent_name()))
```

Comment: Please fix code indentation

Comment: You call `username()` twice, so why don't you expect the prompt to be repeated? If you only want it to be called once, _only call it once_ (and record/reuse the value it returns), or modify the function to record the entered value and return it without reprompting on a second invocation.

Comment: Use f-strings instead of `.format()`.

Comment: ...generally, though, functions are for code you intend to call more than one time. (They also can be reasonable to use for organization of things you're only going to use once, but if that were your intent here it'd be more typical to encapsulate _everything_ in functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're calling `username` twice. Try saving `username`'s value to a variable.**

Save the username (and opponent name) to a variable. Also put the `input('What shall we call you?')` in the `username` function's `if user_name_choice == 'y':` block, so that it is only called if the the person wants to choose their own name (same goes for the opponent name bit):

```
import random

rando_username = ['Yoda', 'Han', 'Luke', 'General Kenobi', 'Mace Windu', 'Padme', 'Anakin', 'Jar Jar Binks']
user_name_choice = input('Would you like to choose your own name for the duel? y/n')

def username():
    if user_name_choice == 'y':
        username = input('What shall we call you?')
    else:
        username = random.choice(rando_username)
    return username

name = username()

rando_opponent = ['Darth Vader', 'Darth Sidious', 'Darth Maul', 'Kylo Ren', 'Jabba the Hutt', 'Moff Gideon', 'Jango Fett', 'General Grievous']
opponent_name_choice = input('Hello there, {}! Would you like to name your enemy? y/n'.format(name))


def opponent_name():
    if opponent_name_choice == 'y':
        opponent_name = input('What shall we call your enemy?')
    else:
         opponent_name = random.choice(rando_opponent)
    return opponent_name

print ('Excellent choice {}, your opponent is {}!'.format(name, opponent_name()))
```

A possible output:

```
Would you like to choose your own name for the duel? y/nn
Hello there, Jar Jar Binks! Would you like to name your enemy? y/nn
Excellent choice Jar Jar Binks, your opponent is Darth Vader!
```

(Note that in this example the functions are no longer really necessary, but I left them in case you still need them)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it makes a lot of sense given my limited understanding. I appreciate your time in helping me

Answer (score 0):

There a few things that I would highlight regarding your code:

- First of all, note that the two methods `username` and `opponent_name` do exactly the same thing: they return an entered name if the `_choice` variables are equal to `y`, otherwise they will pick a random value from a prefined list. You should collapse them in one method, but let's not go there for now.
- You are always setting a `random_username` and `random_opponent`, even when is not needed - i.e. when `_choice` is equal to `y` - clearly, you could save some work there,
- In your code, you are taking advantage of the synchronous nature of the `input` method: in theory, you could even avoid writing `username` and `opponent_name` as method, but you could have everything in a monolitic/sequential code
- Note that everytime you are using the `()` you are calling the method: this could have undesired effects in some situations.

Given this background, I have reorganized your code:

```
import random

# List of username options
random_username = ['Yoda', 'Han', 'Luke', 'General Kenobi', 'Mace Windu', 'Padme', 'Anakin', 'Jar Jar Binks']

# List of opponents options
random_opponent = ['Darth Vader', 'Darth Sidious', 'Darth Maul', 'Kylo Ren', 'Jabba the Hutt', 'Moff Gideon', 'Jango Fett', 'General Grievous']

def username(user_choice):
    if user_choice == 'y':
        username = input('What shall we call you?')
    else:
        # username random selection happens only if needed
        username = random.choice(random_username)
    return username

def opponent_name(opponent_choice):
    if opponent_choice == 'y':
        opponent_name = input('What shall we call your enemy?') 
    else:
        # opponent name random selection happens only if needed
        opponent_name = random.choice(random_opponent)
    return opponent_name
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_name_choice = input('Would you like to choose your own name for the duel [y/n]? ')
    # username name method called only once and assigned to VARIABLE username
    username = username(user_name_choice)
    
    opponent_name_choice = input(f'Hello there, {username}! Would you like to name your enemy [y/n]? ')
    # opponent_name method called only once and assigned to VARIABLE opponent_name
    opponent_name = opponent_name(opponent_name)
    
    print (f'Excellent choice {username}, your opponent is {opponent_name}!')
```

As stressed at the first point, `username` and `opponent_name` methods do exactly the same thing - you collapse the logic as follows, for example:

```
def choose_name(your_choice, available_options, you_or_your_enemy):
    if your_choice == 'y':
        return input(f'What shall we call {you_or_your_enemy}? ')
    else:
        return random.choice(available_options)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_name_choice = input('Would you like to choose your own name for the duel [y/n]? ')
    username = choose_name(user_name_choice, random_username, "you")
    
    opponent_name_choice = input(f'Hello there, {username}! Would you like to name your enemy [y/n]? ')
    opponent_name = choose_name(opponent_name_choice, random_opponent, "your enemy")
    
    print (f'Excellent choice {username}, your opponent is {opponent_name}!')
```